# Display conditionally php content depending on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a line that prints the contact information of a user in his profile. Only logged in user can see the contact information.

```
<?php 
  // Contact Info
?>
```

I have 2 user roles - `supervisor, manager`

What I am trying to achieve is that if the logged in user is a `supervisor` then he can see his own contact info, but he cannot see `manager's` contact.

But If the logged in user is a `manager` then he can see his own contact info, but he can also see `supervisor's` contact info.

I have been trying to use the standard `if current_user_is` function, but this will only display one or the other.

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      if(current_user_is("manager"))
          echo 'Contact Info Here';
      else if(current_user_is("supervisor"))
          echo 'Contact Info Here';
      else if(current_user_is_not("manager"))
          echo 'Restricted contact, must be a manager';
?>
```

I just can't figure out how to make this work, so it displays conditionally.

I also have these rules in the global rule, not sure how relevant it is :

```
$store_user = get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
$store_info = get_store_info( $store_user->ID );
$user_meta = get_user_meta($store_user->ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks like you'll need to call the get_users function and pass the "supervisor" role to get users of that type and display their contact info to the "manager" role.

As you've written it, the contact info being displayed is for the current user. You'll need to grab another role's contact info if that's what you want to display.

Untested but this may be close...

```
//if current user is the manager...
$supervisors = get_users( 'role=supervisor' );
foreach ($supervisors as $supervisor) {
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $supervisor->user_email ) . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your input, would you be able to write the code to see what it should look like ?

Comment: Added a code sample for the simplest case. That's about the best I can do without knowing the actual organizational structure and data you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nothing more than a beginner with php but using 'OR' may help you aggregate roles' conditions on a single piece of content:

```
<?php global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if(current_user_is("manager") OR current_user_is("supervisor"))
        echo 'Contact Info Here';
    else()
        echo 'Restricted contact, must be a manager';
?>
```